# Adding parameters into Razor pages routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm building a helper tool for development purposes in .NET 7, to extract data from different data sources to save having to manually write queries. I want it to run over multiple environments and to be able to share links, so for simplicity wanted the environment to be in the URL.

i.e.

- https://localhost/development/pool/123
- https://localhost/staging/pool/123

As such, we have a page called pool.cshtml, and it takes in an ID parameter, and the environment part of the url is ignored, as it's handled by some middleware.

I've already added in a piece of middleware to extract the environment from the URL and update the `IWebHostEnvironment` so I can get the correct credentials per environment. However, every time I go to the page, I get a 404.

I believe you need to use `services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions()` but just haven't been able to configure it. Do you know how to set this up, so the routing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the codes below:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(op =>
{
    op.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
    {
        foreach(var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
            var c = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.ToString();
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
            {
                Order = -1,
                Template = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName+"/"+c

            };
        }
    });
});
```

It works on myside:

[image]

Update:

```
public class MyConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        //add the enviroment here
        private static readonly string[] AllowedValues = new string[] { "Development", "Production" };

        public bool Match(
            HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey,
            RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var routeValueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (routeValueString is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return AllowedValues.Contains(routeValueString, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRouting(options =>
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("myconstraint", typeof(MyConstraint)));
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(op =>
{
    op.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
    {
        foreach(var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
            var c = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.ToString();
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
            {
                Order = -1,
                Template = "{enviroment:myconstraint}/" + c

            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its progress, but that works for "Development" only, I guess as the routes are registered at start up and the app is launched as Development. However the routes, Test/Production + others are not. So when I go to localhost/Development/Index it loads, but when i click a link and go to localhost/Test/Index it gives 404 not found.  This is a single app, where you can click to switch between environments

Comment: I've got something working, which is similar to your solution on the AttributeRouteModel.Template,

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new EnvironmentPageRouteModelConvention());
    });

public class EnvironmentPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = "{environment}/" + selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
        }
    }
}

Comment: So you want it be able to switch to production when you are in development? check what I've updated in my answer

Comment: I suggest you add a constranit to your enviroment section

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. However, I've fooled myself in thinking I can switch between appsettings.development.json and  appsettings.test.json based on the request, of course you cannot, as its done at start up. So I'll have to add all my settings into the single appsettings.json file. The drawback of using 1 application instead of many, maybe running multiple apps is a better approach.